# What is the default size of printable PDF of photography magazine in In Design?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

What is the default size of  printable PDF of photography magazine in In Design?
I like to make photography magazine for online as well as print.
I want to know is there any standard size photography magazine in In Design.

Answer (score 4):

**There is no standard size.**

You're free to create a magazine at whatever size you want. Customarily a more vertical rectangle is used, but there are several magazines who utilize a more square shape.